# How-to integrate a gradle module into a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-3

We have maven parent project with 2 maven modules. Now we need a new maven module, but the building process depends on a gradle build. The problem is, that the new module is a plugin for third-party software and they only provide a gradle plugin for a proper build. Also we need the other modules as dependcies, which isn't a big deal, but we want to have it in the same code repository. My question is now, is it possible to integrate gradle in a maven project. Maybe with the maven plugin, which generates the pom, so that it looks like a maven-module, but we can also use the gradle plugin, if we need so.
We use maven v3 and it's a java project if these informations are relevant.

Comment: Since your provider is dragging you to gradle, have you considered to build with gradle the rest of your project?

Comment: The problem is, that we used gradle never before. So the other developers won't use gradle for the hole project if there is a other possibility.

Comment: Just let gradle deploy the artifact to your repository manager (or may be you need to do that manually) and reuse at usual dependency. That's it.

Comment: If the provided Gradle plugin doesn't do anything particularly complex or hidden, another option is to write a Maven plugin that does the same thing.  Also, are you free to say what this 3rd party software is? Knowing what it is might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the Maven "exec-maven-plugin".
With this plugin you can run cmd Commands.

So add the plugin and let it execute your Gradle build

```
<project>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Gradle Executor</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>Your Gradle Executable</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
</project>
```

This should work, give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll try it. Do I need to put the external dependcies into gradle and maven, since gradle runs a whole build process or is it enough if they are only in maven configured?

Comment: I think you dont have to add any dependencies, because maven only starts the Grandle Process and it makes no difference whether it startes your grandle Process or any other Batch programm.

Comment: I added the dependencies in both build-tools, since both compile code. And so we can use maven also for tests in this module.

Comment: how to include gradle plugin com.apollographql.android at my pom.xml? please share the sample pom.xml